# Unresolved reference 'DeserializeFromUInt16' using ANTLR for Go

Tags: go, antlr, antlr4

I'm creating a grammar to run a console application, using VSCode or IntelliJ extensions everything seems fine with my .g4 grammar file. But when I execute the command to get the antlr/parser folder:

```
antlr4 -Dlanguage=Go -o parser items.g4
```

I get the following errors from the items_lexer.go and items_parser.go files:

- Unresolved reference 'DeserializeFromUInt16'
- Unresolved reference 'DecisionToState'
- Unresolved reference 'DecisionToState'

The first one appears in the following line:

```
var lexerAtn = lexerDeserializer.DeserializeFromUInt16(serializedLexerAtn)
```

Which uses the var: lexerDeserializer declared in the previous line:

```
var lexerDeserializer = antlr.NewATNDeserializer(nil)
```

And here is the origin of the problem, directly from antlr lib for some reason the DeserializeFromUInt16 func is not founded. I already tried using another grammar. Im using ANTRL 4.7.2, and I made sure to had  a jdk installed, the `go get github.com/antlr/antlr4/runtime/Go/antlr`, and the .jar folder in my project.

I would appreciate any kind of suggestions about how can I free my files from errors.

Comment: Which runtime do you use? Has it the same version as the ANTLR tool?

Comment: You need to add the specific dependency `go get github.com/antlr/antlr4/runtime/Go/antlr@4.7.2`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue today, since I used ANTLR 4.7 for code-generation and v1.4.10 as the golang dependency (see the go.mod file).

Updating to ANTLR 4.10 for code-generation helps.